# Errors compiling a GHC program in Quipper

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghc, quantum-computing

I am trying to compile a program in Quipper, the official Quantum Programming Language from this site:
http://mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/quipper/

I am having trouble getting it to compile, which I assume must be a problem related to GHC or Haskell, as Quipper itself has no outstanding bugs.

I compile my program using these commands:

```
cd ~/quipper-0.8/quipper/scripts/
sudo ./quipper ~/quipper-0.8/tests/name.hs
```

The error I receive looks like this:

```
[13 of 21] Compiling Quipper.QData    ( ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs, ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.o )

../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:965:20:
Could not deduce (QCType Bool Bool s0
                  ~ QCType Int Bool (QCType Bit Bit s))
from the context (QData s)
  bound by the type signature for
             qdata_promote_c :: QData s =>
                                BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
  at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:965:20-71
NB: ‘QCType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
  Actual type: BType s0 -> CType s0 -> ErrMsg -> BType s0
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘qdata_promote_c’:
  qdata_promote_c :: forall s.
                     QData s =>
                     BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘qdata_promote_c’:
  qdata_promote_c :: (QData s) =>
                     BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
```

The referenced line of code in `QData.hs` looks like this:

```
-- | Like 'qdata_promote', except take a piece of classical data.
qdata_promote_c :: (QData s) => BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
qdata_promote_c b c s = qdata_promote b q s where
q = qdata_map (shapetype_c c) map_qubit c

map_qubit :: Bit -> Qubit
map_qubit = const qubit
```

Apparently that's the only part of the code it has a problem with in `QData.hs`, but when I comment it out I get this error:

```
[13 of 21] Compiling Quipper.QData    ( ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs, ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.o )
[14 of 21] Compiling Quipper.Generic  ( ../../quipper/Quipper/Generic.hs, ../../quipper/Quipper/Generic.o )

../../quipper/Quipper/Generic.hs:257:13:
Not in scope: ‘qdata_promote_c’
Perhaps you meant one of these:
  ‘qdata_promote’ (imported from Quipper.QData),
  ‘qcdata_promote’ (imported from Quipper.QData)
```

As you can see, this time it accepted `[13 of 21]` but broke on 14, as it depended on the function I commented out. When I try to follow its suggestion, and add AllowAmbiguousTypes:

```
sudo ./quipper ~/quipper-0.8/tests/name.hs -XAllowAmbiguousTypes
```

I get much more errors:

```
[13 of 21] Compiling Quipper.QData    ( ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs, ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.o )

../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:25:
Could not deduce (QCType
                    Bool Bool (QCType Qubit Qubit (QCType Qubit Qubit s0))
                  ~ QCType Int Bool (QCType Bit Bit s))
from the context (QData s)
  bound by the type signature for
             qdata_promote_c :: QData s =>
                                BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
  at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:965:20-71
NB: ‘QCType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: BType s
  Actual type: BType (HType Qubit s0)
Relevant bindings include
  q :: HType Qubit s0 (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:967:3)
  c :: CType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:19)
  b :: BType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:17)
  qdata_promote_c :: BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
    (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:1)
In the expression: qdata_promote b q s
In an equation for ‘qdata_promote_c’:
    qdata_promote_c b c s
      = qdata_promote b q s
      where
          q = qdata_map (shapetype_c c) map_qubit c
          map_qubit :: Bit -> Qubit
          map_qubit = const qubit

../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:967:30:
Could not deduce (QCType Bit Bit s0 ~ QCType Bit Bit s)
from the context (QData s)
  bound by the type signature for
             qdata_promote_c :: QData s =>
                                BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
  at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:965:20-71
NB: ‘QCType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: CType s0
  Actual type: CType s
Relevant bindings include
  q :: HType Qubit s0 (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:967:3)
  c :: CType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:19)
  b :: BType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:17)
  qdata_promote_c :: BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
    (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:1)
In the first argument of ‘shapetype_c’, namely ‘c’
In the first argument of ‘qdata_map’, namely ‘(shapetype_c c)’

../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:967:43:
Could not deduce (QCType Bit Bit (QCType Qubit Qubit s0)
                  ~ QCType Bit Bit s)
from the context (QData s)
  bound by the type signature for
             qdata_promote_c :: QData s =>
                                BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
  at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:965:20-71
NB: ‘QCType’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
Expected type: HType Bit s0
  Actual type: CType s
Relevant bindings include
  q :: HType Qubit s0 (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:967:3)
  c :: CType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:19)
  b :: BType s (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:17)
  qdata_promote_c :: BType s -> CType s -> ErrMsg -> BType s
    (bound at ../../quipper/Quipper/QData.hs:966:1)
In the third argument of ‘qdata_map’, namely ‘c’
In the expression: qdata_map (shapetype_c c) map_qubit c
```

Which all stems from the exact same line I quoted above from `QData.hs`. Note none of these errors apparently has anything to do with my own code in `name.hs`.

I've noticed this site doesn't have direct help from Quipper (and I've emailed both people in charge of Quipper with no response), but I'm pretty sure this is a problem from the way I'm compiling it, as these error messages don't come from Quipper but from GHC or Haskell.

So anyway, any help to get to the bottom of this would be appreciated,
Nathan

Comment: What version of GHC are you using? Quipper uses a lot of advanced type-level machinery that is a bit brittle to GHC versions. I remember trying to patch Quipper to run on 7.10 and my errors were similar. AFAIK, 7.10 simple doesn't work with Quipper...

Comment: I don't know anything about Quipper but the error suggest adding a `Proxy s` arg to `q_data_promotec` might help. Alternatively, you may use AmbiguousTypes, but this would require also using TypeApplications to specify the ambiguous type at every use site. Depending on what the entire body of code looks like, one or the other may be more convenient for you.

Comment: Alec well the version I have apparently is 7.10.3: `ghc:amd64/xenial 7.10.3-7 uptodate`. I followed the instructions on https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/#linux and ran `stack setup`, which installed ghc 8.0.2. But when the problem above persisted, and when I checked the version of GHC again it still shows as 7.10.3 WTH?!

Comment: User24 this is my first time programming in haskell, so I'm not completely sure where I add the arg to

Comment: @NathanGoedeke Unfortunately, if you aren't familiar with some of the more advanced type level features of Haskell (and to be familiar with these, you must be familiar with the basics, of course) you'll find it very difficult to use a library which makes use of such advanced type level features.